# How to create a linked database via Notion API?

Tags: notion-api, notion

Manually, I can create a linked database (see the attached image) and then put it under a page, in notion. So far, so good. On the attached image, you can see the arrow on the left and it shows that this is a linked database.

When I fetch that block via Notion API, I see that this block type is called "child_database". My goal is to create that "child_database" via API.

Notion API [tells me that](https://developers.notion.com/reference/block#child-database-blocks) I need to create a database and then update it to create a child database. But, when I do that, it does NOT create a linked database, it creates a NEW database.

So, my question is how to create a linked database via Notion API?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?